# a script that will erase a row after it has been emailed

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently creating a sheet that sends emails to the contractors when they are getting close to a deadline or are over it and it sends them an email, i have managed to get that to work but I would also like a script that will send an email to the admin once they put in the completion date and then erase the row that it was placed on

this is my current script that I'm using.

```
 //setup function
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Quoting');
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,11);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";
 //iterate loop
 for (i in AllValues) {

 //set current row
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];


  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var endDate = date

 //define column to check if sent (starts from "0" not "1")
 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[7];

 //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
 if (EmailSent == "1") 
     continue;

 if (EmailSent == "2") 
     continue;

  if (EmailSent == "3") 
    continue;

  if (EmailSent == "4") 
    continue;

   if (EmailSent == "5") 
    continue;

  if (EmailSent == "6") 
    continue;

  if (EmailSent == "")
    continue;

  message +=
    "This Quote is completed" +
    "<p><b>Project No: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
    "<p><b>Builder: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
    "<p><b>Quoted By: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
    "<p><b>Due Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
    "<p><b>notes: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>";

  //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  //mark row as "sent"
  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 8).setValue("Completion Email sent " + endDate);

  var SendTo = "insert email address";

 //set subject line
 var Subject = "Quote is Complete";

  MailApp.sendEmail(SendTo, Subject, message, {
      htmlBody: message,

 })
 }
}
```

i have tired many methods but i don't seem to get it too work, can someone please help me

Comment: what column is the completion date entered?

Comment: the completion date is added in column E

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const cA = ["", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Quoting');
  const sr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 11).getValues();
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let message = 
      "This Quote is completed" +
      "<p><b>Project No: </b>" + r[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Builder: </b>" + r[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Quoted By: </b>" + r[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Due Date: </b>" + r[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>notes: </b>" + r[5] + "</p>";
    if(!~cA.indexOf(r[7]) && r[4]) {
      MailApp.sendEmail("insert email address", "Quote is Complete", message, { htmlBody: message })
      sh.deleteRow(i + sr - d++);
    }
  });
}
```